# Subscription query always throws AxonServerException: CANCELLED: AXONIQ-5000

Tags: axon, axon-framework

- **Axon framework version** : 4.4.7
- **Axon server** : 4.5.7

```
@Component
@ProcessingGroup("product-group")
public class ProductEventHandler {
    private final ProductRepository productsRepository;
    private final QueryUpdateEmitter queryUpdateEmitter;

    public ProductEventHandler(ProductRepository productsRepository, QueryUpdateEmitter queryUpdateEmitter) {
        this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
        this.queryUpdateEmitter = queryUpdateEmitter;
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void handle(ProductCreatedEvent event) throws Exception {
        ProductEntity entity = new ProductEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(event, entity);
        try {
            productsRepository.save(entity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void handle(ProductUpdatedEvent event) {
        ProductEntity entity = new ProductEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(event, entity);
        try {
            productsRepository.save(entity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        ProductResponse productResponse = new ProductResponse();
        productResponse.setProductId(event.getProductId());
        productResponse.setStatus("Updated");

        //queryUpdateEmitter.emit(FetchProductQuery.class, query -> true, productResponse);
        queryUpdateEmitter.emit(FetchProductQuery.class, 
            query -> query.getProductId().equals(event.getProductId()), productResponse);
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;
    private final QueryGateway queryGateway;
    private SubscriptionQueryResult<ProductResponse, ProductResponse> queryResult;
    
    @Autowired
    public ProductController(CommandGateway commandGateway, QueryGateway queryGateway) {
        this.queryGateway = queryGateway;
        this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ProductResponse updateProduct(@PathVariable("id") String id,
            @Valid @RequestBody ProductRequest request) {
            
        UpdateProductCommand updateProductCommand = UpdateProductCommand.builder().productId(id)
                .price(request.getPrice()).quantity(request.getQuantity()).title(request.getTitle()).build();
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(updateProductCommand);

        queryResult = queryGateway.subscriptionQuery(
                FetchProductQuery.builder().productId(id), ResponseTypes.instanceOf(ProductResponse.class),
                ResponseTypes.instanceOf(ProductResponse.class));
        try {
            // return queryResult.updates().blockFirst();
            return queryResult.initialResult().block();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            queryResult.close();
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class ProductsQueryHandler {
    private final ProductRepository productsRepository;
    public ProductsQueryHandler(ProductRepository productsRepository) {
        this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }
    @QueryHandler
    public ProductResponse handler(FetchProductQuery query) {
        ProductEntity productEntity = productsRepository.findByProductId(query.getProductId());
        ProductResponse productResponse = new ProductResponse();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(productEntity, productResponse);
        return productResponse;
    }
}
```

**I could not see any subscription queries in AXON dashboard, getting below error. Can you please help me for the cause and solution???**

```
2021-10-21 18:09:42.468[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19608[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.m.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Dispatched messages: [FetchProductQueryBuilder]
org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.AxonServerException: CANCELLED: AXONIQ-5000
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.lambda$static$24(ErrorCode.java:145)
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.convert(ErrorCode.java:182)
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.convert(ErrorCode.java:213)
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.convert(ErrorCode.java:202)
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.event.util.GrpcExceptionParser.parse(GrpcExceptionParser.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3437)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(MonoCompletionStage.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:883)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2321)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:143)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.subscribe(MonoCompletionStage.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4099)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1702)
    at com.demo.product.controller.ProductController.updateProduct(ProductController.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703)
        ... 51 more
[2m2021-10-21 18:09:42.493[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m19608[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-2][0;39m [36m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.AxonServerException: CANCELLED: AXONIQ-5
000]
```

Comment: Please provide feedback when you downvote a post.

Answer (score 3):

The error code AXONIQ-5000 indicates that no query handler for the given query request type could be found.
I don't have the complete code, of course, but checking the code it looks like the first parameter of the query request is a builder (the result of FetchProductQuery.builder().productId(id)) and not a FetchProductQuery instance.

Comment: Thanks Marc, you are right. Forgot to put build() on the builder.